# A follow option: how does it work?

Tags: discussion, support, design

I recently saw this addition at the bottom of posts:

[image]

What does this *follow* option provide? Is there any guide that mentions what I can do and don't do with it? Who has used this *follow* option and for what?

Comment: Very often when one reads questions one can't help the feeling that one cannot quite follow the logic of the presentation. The `follow` button is supposed to cure this. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat But surely there must be other reasons why they added it. Do you think many users will use this option?

Comment: See [this announcement on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/300001).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you very much. If you want put an answer of your comment I am very happy to read it. Best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The follow button is meant to give you inbox notifications for any changes related to that question or answer. Yes, it is specific to post that you follow, either an answer or a question. Here is the original pop-up notification pointing to the follow button:

[image]

Use cases here could vary. For some, they may downvote a poor question with some suggested changes in comments. Once the post is edited, they'll receive a notification in their inbox, when they can revisit the post and see whether their suggestions have been implemented (and reverse the voting). Others may literally want to follow changes to a heavily-linked post that might be on a site (like Meta.SE, say) they don't visit often to keep track of any updates.

It's currently still under development and there might be short-term changes to fix bugs and implement new features.

Source: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/168244)

<sub>This was actually something [I requested about 3 years ago](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/215) to form part of the [SOX Stack App](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox). It has since been [implemented as a separate browser extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/8278/stack-exchange-post-watcher-firefox-chrome-extension-to-watch-posts-for-any). However, it may become obsolete based on this native implementation by Stack Exchange.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. There is also a user that he/she has voted negative a simple and clear question. Boh.